# React-Native "/Components` could not be found from " Error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is my first question on Stack.
I am trying to run react-native project.But i have this problem
i tried to start with npx,lots of times delete node modules and reinstall npm.
Also at every starting use -- --reset-cache. and run  "npm install then react-native upgrade --legacy"

```
 
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.14.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.3",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.0",
    "@thecodingmachine/redux-toolkit-wrapper": "^1.3.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "i18next": "^19.9.1",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.6",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-i18next": "^11.8.8",
    "react-native": "^0.59.9",
    "react-native-appearance": "^0.3.4",
    "react-native-flipper": "^0.78.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.16",
    "react-native-onboarding-swiper": "^1.1.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.18.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-native": "^5.2.0",
    "reactjs-components": "^5.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-flipper": "^1.4.2",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "then": "0.0.1",
    "upgrade": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.13.1",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.13.7",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.21.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-babel-module": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "jest": "26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.65.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "setupFiles": [
      "./jest.setup.js"
    ],
    "timers": "fake",
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom"
```

i tried lots of things but here is the conclusion;

````
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `../../Components` from `/home/egehan/Masaüstü/mobile-master/src/Containers/Example/Index.js`: The module `../../Components` could not be found from `/home/egehan/Masaüstü/mobile-master/src/Containers/Example/Index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
  * `/home/egehan/Masaüstü/mobile-master/src/Components(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)  ```
````